# Group XML using xsl1.0 based on header value and lineItems

Tags: xslt

I have an Orders XML input file where based on the Matching 'ref' XML tag and 'Shipto' XML tag, the order should be split with multiple batch orders.

**Input xml:**

```
<Purchase>
    <Order>
        <Header>
        <Ref>13400</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>AAA</ShipTo>                
            </ShipToDetails>
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
        </Items>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Header>
        <Ref>13400</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>BBB</ShipTo>
            </ShipToDetails>            
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
        </Items>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Header>
        <Ref>13401</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>CCC</ShipTo>
            </ShipToDetails>            
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
        </Items>
    </Order>
        <Order>
        <Header>
        <Ref>13401</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>CCC</ShipTo>
            </ShipToDetails>            
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800101</LineItem>
        </Items>
    </Order>
</Purchase>
```

**Expected output:**

```
        <Header>
        <Ref>13400</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>AAA</ShipTo>                
            </ShipToDetails>
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
        </Items>
</Batchorder>
<Batchorder>
        <Header>
        <Ref>13400</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>BBB</ShipTo>                
            </ShipToDetails>
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
        </Items>
</Batchorder>
<Batchorder>
        <Header>
        <Ref>13401</Ref>
            <ShipToDetails>
                <ShipTo>CCC</ShipTo>                
            </ShipToDetails>
        </Header>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
        </Items>
        <Items>
            <LineItem>800101</LineItem>
        </Items>
</Batchorder>
```

I have tried with below **XSL1.0**, but I get only the Partial output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="Orders" match="Header" use="Ref"/>
    <xsl:template match="Purchase">
            <xsl:for-each select="/Purchase/Order/Header[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Orders',Ref)[1])]">
                    <Batchorder>
                        <header>
                                <OrderType>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../Ref"/>
                                </OrderType>                                
                                <ShipToDetails>                                 
                                    <ShipTo>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="ShipTo"/>
                                    </ShipTo>                               
                                </ShipToDetails>                                
                            </header>
                            <Items>
                                <LineItem>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../Items/LineItem"/>
                                </LineItem>
                            </Items>
                    </Batchorder>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am looking for an **xsl1.0** solution, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XSLT code to the following. It uses a concatenated string for the `xsl:key` to combine the `Ref` and the `ShipTo` value as an index.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="Orders" match="Order" use="concat(Header/Ref,'_',Header/ShipToDetails/ShipTo)"/>

    <xsl:template match="Purchase">
            <xsl:for-each select="Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Orders',concat(Header/Ref,'_',Header/ShipToDetails/ShipTo))[1])]">
                    <Batchorder>
                        <Header>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="Header/Ref | Header/ShipToDetails"/>
                        </Header>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('Orders',concat(Header/Ref,'_',Header/ShipToDetails/ShipTo))">
                            <Items>
                                <LineItem>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Items/LineItem"/>
                                </LineItem>
                            </Items>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Batchorder>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Batchorder>
    <Header>
        <Ref>13400</Ref>
        <ShipToDetails>
            <ShipTo>AAA</ShipTo>

        </ShipToDetails>
    </Header>
    <Items>
        <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
    </Items>
</Batchorder>
<Batchorder>
    <Header>
        <Ref>13400</Ref>
        <ShipToDetails>
            <ShipTo>BBB</ShipTo>
        </ShipToDetails>
    </Header>
    <Items>
        <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
    </Items>
</Batchorder>
<Batchorder>
    <Header>
        <Ref>13401</Ref>
        <ShipToDetails>
            <ShipTo>CCC</ShipTo>
        </ShipToDetails>
    </Header>
    <Items>
        <LineItem>800100</LineItem>
    </Items>
    <Items>
        <LineItem>800101</LineItem>
    </Items>
</Batchorder>
```

The output is not XML-1.0 conform because it doesn't have a single root element. Add an `<xsl:copy>` to the template to replicate the `<Purchase>` element if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support and it works as expected ! Happy that I learned new thing today. Thanks